# How to implement RefreshCommand for ListView in Xamarin.Froms with F#

Tags: listview, f#, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms project contains shared PCL in F#. I have implemented RefreshCommand for my listview but it is not doing anything. How should it be written?

This is SomePage.xaml's part of ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="someList"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadListCommand}">
```

This is my SomePage.fs:

```
type SomePage() = 
    inherit ContentPage()

    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<SomePage>)
    let someList = base.FindByName<ListView>("someList")

    do someList.ItemsSource <- sList

    let someFun arg =   
        someList.ItemsSource <- arg :: sList
        someList.IsRefreshing <- false

    member this.LoadListCommand = new Command(fun() -> someFun s3)
```

Comment: `someFun` is a value, not a function. To make it a function, give it some parameters.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I tried that but it isn't working

Comment: Care to add any actionable details?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are going the [data binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/#Data_Binding) route then your `sList` needs to either be of type `Observable Collection` or implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`[[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)]. Typically You want to have a View Model that inherits from a View Model Base implements what you need. This in and of itself can be a bit of a hassle and I'd recommend you use and existing nuget package like [FSharp.ViewModule](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.ViewModule)
and checkout some of the [examples](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/tree/master/demos).

If you are not then you can directly bind to the UI via Routed Events. The xaml for that is a bit different. 
[Routed Events In Xaml](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/xaml/events-in-xaml/)